# Unable to highlight top of pdfs in iBooks

Tags: ipad, pdf, books

Highlighting text in a pdf with iBooks is quite convenient unless I am trying to highlight some text at the top of the page. The toolbar then hide what I want to highlight.

See the screenshots below where the first line gets hidden:
[image: text without toolbar]
[image: text with toolbar]

How can I circumvent this?